# Run JIRA in port 80 as root

Tags: centos, jira, root, port80

i want to access my JIRA installation on Port 80.
System: CentOS7
Jira-Version: 7.0.0

I edited the server.xml from

> Connector port="8080"

to

> Connector port="80"

and set the jira-user into the root-group with

> usermod -a -G root jira

But if i want to open the server-url, there is no connection

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Afet restarting the service JIRA

There is a logfile-view

```
08-Nov-2015 16:23:47.076 SEVERE [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-80"]
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)

08-Nov-2015 16:23:47.078 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-80]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:851)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:599)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:310)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:484)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:962)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:437)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:429)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:343)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:730)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:457)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:120)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:960)
        ... 13 more
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: port may be busy with another application..ex:Skype also running on the port 80 I think.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check this link:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Unable+to+Access+JIRA+due+to+BindException+Permission+Denied

Anyway the solution they recommend is to reroute port 80:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```